# QuantLib was not compiled with intraday support

Tags: python, python-3.6, quantlib, quantlib-swig

Compiled QuantLib v1.11 on Mac 10.12.6 with standard options from documentation with *intraday support enabled*:

```
./configure --with-boost-include=/usr/local/include/ \
            --with-boost-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --prefix=/usr/local/ \
            CXXFLAGS='-O2 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9' \
            LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9' \
            --enable-intraday
```

Installed QuantLib for Anaconda Python 3.6.2:

```
pip install QuantLib-Python
```

Tried to create an intraday `ql.Date` object which fails:

```
>>> import QuantLib as ql
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> now = dt.datetime.today()
>>> ql.Date(now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/QuantLib/QuantLib.py", line 433, in __init__
    this = _QuantLib.new_Date(*args)
RuntimeError: QuantLib was not compiled with intraday support
```

Is this is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

(Cross posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues/99))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of QuantLib-Python that you installed using `pip` comes with its own static version of the library, and doesn't link to the one you compiled.  If you want to use the latter, you'll have to compile the wrappers yourself.